# Magento CPU 100% utilization even when less traffic

Tags: tests

we have three store magento sites installed in server on a single instance.
the cpu is going for 100% usage for just very less traffic.

Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: Are you able to provide more info or a link to the site?

Comment: can you validate, this is causes by the php part of the requests, and also that it is not caused by a cronjob but real web requests?
all caches and indexes working?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the load is caused by Magento?

To make sure, i'd suggest 2 things:

- Stop your webserver for a short time. Is the load still high?
- Stop your magento cronjobs. Does this help?

Finding your way to this answer involves narrowing down the possible causes.

Also, does your server meet the system requirements? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html

Running the Magento profiler may also help to discover what is taking time. Details on the profiler can be read here: https://mirasvit.com/doc/common/profiler

Using the profiler is intended for developers though.